# How to update Org to latest version using package repo's / git clone in Ubuntu

Tags: org-mode, package, package-repositories

See the image below.

[image: package-list-packages - output screen].

I want to update my `org` from `Version: 2016071` to `Version 20161003`.

It does not give me an option to upgrade when I use the `package-list-packages` command.

An additional question is when the packages get loaded and I push the "U" key - it tells me one package is marked for upgrade.  How to find out which package is marked and how to activate the upgrade action?

**Update-1:**

I just found out by accident (co-incidence) the solution to part of my problem.

In order to activate an upgrade a package from the list of packages press "x". This will upgrade the marked package.

As a coincidence it turned out that `org` package was the one marked for upgrade and pressing "x" upgraded it.

**Update-2:**
Even though I upgraded just now, my org version is still `Org-mode version 7.9.3f (release_7.9.3f-17-g7524ef` while my org-mode in Windows (with 64 bit Emacs from sourceforge) has `Org-mode version 8.2.10 (release_8.2.10`

In order to get the latest version of Org, I referred the [org-manual](http://orgmode.org/manual/Installation.html) and used the `Using Org's git repository` method.

I did
 - make autoloads
 - make

And got the following error

```
make[1]: Entering directory `/home/prasannarajaram/org-mode/doc'
org-version: 8.3.6 (release_8.3.6-1203-g966e0b)
makeinfo --no-split org.texi -o org
make[1]: makeinfo: Command not found
make[1]: *** [org] Error 127
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/prasannarajaram/org-mode/doc'
make: *** [info] Error 2
```

And now I'm completely stuck!

Answer (score 8):

Add:

```
(require 'package)
(setq package-archives
      '(("melpa" . "https://melpa.org/packages/")
        ("gnu" . "https://elpa.gnu.org/packages/")
        ("org" . "http://orgmode.org/elpa/")))
(package-initialize)
```

to your emacs init file. Adding the org repo will put the latest version of org-mode in `list-packages`, where you can update it just like any other package (e.g. press `U x` then answer prompts to upgrade all packages).

Answer (score 0):

Install from source.  Here are my possibility dates instructions in a shell script

https://github.com/eludom/HOWTO/blob/master/getLatestOrg.sh

Comment: I did the exact same thing as your script does. I'm stuck when I compile using `make`. Is there any way I could fix the error I'm getting (last part of my question)?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue like you and no solution I've found worked. That's what I did eventually.

- git clone git://orgmode.org/org-mode.git
- make

That didn't work and emacs still loaded the old org version. So I deleted all files in /usr/local/share/emacs/25.1/lisp/org and then copied the files from org-mode/lisp into that directory. Now I've got Org mode version 9.0.

If you use `org-version` you can see the path of the currently used org files.