# How to install latest version of org mode?

Tags: org-mode, git

I want to update to the latest version of Org-mode to test a bug fix. I followed the [instructions](https://orgmode.org/manual/Installation.html):

```
cd ~/src/
git clone https://code.orgmode.org/bzg/org-mode.git
cd org-mode/
make autoloads
```

Then I launch emacs without initialization:

```
emacs -nw -q
```

and evaluate:

```lisp
(add-to-list 'load-path "~/src/org-mode/lisp") ;; result: ("~/src/org-mode/lisp" ...)
(org-version)  ;; result: "9.1.9"
```

which shows that it is using the built-in version, not the one from git (the compiled file `org-version.el` shows `"9.3.3"`).

I was able to install the latest version when I filed the bug report. Then `package-list-packages` would show the built-in `org` package as masked by another; I can't remember how I did it and now the built-in package is not masked.

I am on `macOS 10.14.6` and `GNU Emacs 26.3 (build 1, x86_64-apple-darwin18.2.0, NS appkit-1671.20 Version 10.14.3 (Build 18D109)) of 2019-09-02`.

I have tried [How to update Org to latest version using package repo's / git clone in Ubuntu](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/27597/how-to-update-org-to-latest-version-using-package-repos-git-clone-in-ubuntu) without success. [This thread](https://askubuntu.com/questions/348999/how-to-use-the-latest-stable-version-of-org-mode) is for Ubuntu.

What is preventing my machine from using the latest version of org-mode?

Comment: Did you byte-compile the files in the working copy? Emacs first looks for the byte-compiled files. So if your version is not byte-compiled but the built-in version is, the built-in version wins. I think `make` will do that for you. Run `make` and afterwards `make autoloads`.

Comment: I believe it should work without byte-compiling (provided that you add the directory to the front of `load-path`, as you are doing), but you need to `(require 'org-loaddefs)`.

Comment: @NickD You are right. I just tried it: `~/path1/lib.el` shadows `~/path2/lib.elc` if `~/path1` comes before `~/path2` in `load-path` even if `.elc` comes before `.el` in variable `load-suffixes`. I checked the doc strings and the info manual comprehensively. The hierarchy of the searches for `load-path` and `load-suffixes` is not mentioned anywhere. From my point of view that is a documentation bug.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[As requested, expanding the comment into an answer]

The main idea is that you need to make sure that Org mode is set up, using the new bits that you downloaded *only*. Emacs comes with a version of Org mode bundled up with it, but that is inevitably older than what is available from the Org mode git repo. It is important to avoid loading *any* piece from the bundled up version or else you might end up with a "mixed" installation (there are many hits for that on the Org mode mailing list).

As I mention in a comment, and @Tobias has verified in another comment, you do not need to byte-compile the new version - you only need to `make autoloads`. That creates an `org-loaddefs.el` file, so that all the common entry points into org will, when first invoked, load the appropriate file first. It is important (and contrary to what the OP states in his (now deleted) comment) to set the `load-path` *before* loading the `org-loaddefs.el` file: otherwise, you may end up with the dreaded "mixed" install I mentioned above.

So after cloning or updating the git repo into, say, `~/src/org-mode`, you can do
`make autoloads` (or just `make` if you want to byte-compile the `.el` files). Then
invoke emacs with an init file like this:

```
(add-to-list 'load-path "~/src/org-mode/lisp")
(require 'org-loaddefs)

...
```

and make sure that those two lines are *before* anything else in the init file, just to make sure that *nobody* loads any old pieces of org-mode that may be lying around. Setting the load-path to begin with will shadow the old pieces and will prevent them from being loaded later.

The [Org mode manual](https://orgmode.org/manual/index.html) has a [section](https://orgmode.org/manual/Installation.html#Installation) on installing (including a subsection on installing from the git repo).

Comment: Does not work for me: I've added
```
(add-to-list 'load-path "~/src/org-mode/lisp")
(require 'org-loaddefs)
```
as the very first thing in my `.emacs.d/config.org`, but when I type `M-x org-version` I get a very strange message telling me the loaded version *number* is the built-in one but the *path* it was loaded from is the configured `load-path` one....

Comment: `config.org` is not the emacs init file: try `~/.emacs.d/init.el` instead. You might have a [mixed installation](https://orgmode.org/worg/org-faq.html#mixed-install)